Libclang c++ cannot parse nested template field declaration
We want to parse the following source file:
#pragma once

#include "Vec3.h"

template<typename T> struct Array;

struct S1
{
    int S1i;
    Array<Array<Vec3>> S1Grid;
};

struct S2
{
    int S2i;
    Array<Array<Vec3> > S2Grid;
};

struct S3
{
    int S3i;
    Array<Array<char>> S3Grid;
};

Using the following parser code:
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
#include <string>

static CXChildVisitResult CursorVisitorTest(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor parent, CXClientData client_data)
{
    CXCursorKind Kind = clang_getCursorKind(cursor);
    printf("%d %s\n", Kind, clang_getCString(clang_getCursorSpelling(cursor)));
    return CXChildVisit_Recurse;
}

void Test()
{
    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    std::string header_path = "Example.h";
    CXTranslationUnit TranslationUnit;
    static const char* args[] = { "-std=c++17", "-xc++", "-DHEADER_TOOL" };
    CXErrorCode error = clang_parseTranslationUnit2(
        index,
        header_path.c_str(),
        args,
        3,
        nullptr,
        0,
        CXTranslationUnit_SingleFileParse,
        &TranslationUnit
    );
    if (error == CXError_Success && TranslationUnit != nullptr)
    {
        CXCursor cursor = clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(TranslationUnit);
        clang_visitChildren(cursor, &CursorVisitorTest, nullptr);
        clang_disposeTranslationUnit(TranslationUnit);
    }
}

We obtained the following output:
31 Array
27 T
2 S1
6 S1i
2 S2
6 S2i
6 S2Grid
2 S3
6 S3i
6 S3Grid
45 Array
45 Array

We observed that Clang fails to parse S1Grid as a field. Judging by the fact that S2Grid is properly parsed, we suspected >> in S1Gird's type is parsed as a right shift. Interestingly, S3Grid is also properly parsed. Probably because char is a built-in type and Vec3 is not?
What can we do to make lib clang parse nested template correctly without manually adding a space in the source?
Clang version returned by clang_getClangVersion is clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)

I don't know how the parsers work but could the problem be that Array<Array<char>>  is an incomplete type?

Nope. It wouldn't be able to parse Array<Array<char> > Grid; if that's the case. This is the tokenizer step that clang is having trouble with.

What version of clang are you using?  And how did you determine that it "fails to parse Grid as a field"?

@ScottMcPeak Question updated to include additional information.

Thanks for the additional info.  However, I still can't reproduce any problem when using the provided code and Clang 9.0.0; I see two FieldDecls, one of which is for Grid.  I suggest that you edit the question to include a complete program that can be compiled and run, with print statements in CursorVisitTest, and also include the output from running that program and its presumably missing FieldDecl output.

@ScottMcPeak Thank you for your time and sorry for all the back and forth. I thought this is a simple issue of me missing a flag or not having the latest version. I did not want to expose too much of our code base either. Question has been updated with minimal compilable example code.

The primary issue is error recovery
The input file, Example.h, contains syntax errors.  First, there is an
#include of Vec3.h that is not found.  If that is fixed (by just
commenting it out) then Clang reports the additional errors,
specifically that Vec3 is an undeclared identifier, which is what is
causing the problem.
Because there are syntax errors, Clang attempts to provide a "best
effort" parse of what the code is supposed to mean, but it necessarily
must use some heuristics to deal with the errors, and those heuristics
are imperfect.  When using Clang 9, and this particular input, the
recovery heuristics evidently fail to recognize the >> as the closing
delimiter of nested template-ids, and consequently S1Grid is not
recorded as a field in the resulting AST.
Solution #1: Fix the input code
Although Clang can be used to parse code containing syntax errors, and
is regularly used in that way for IDE support, that isn't what it was
originally designed to do, and in any case the heuristics are always
going to be imperfect.  So the simplest solution is to ensure that the
code is free of syntax errors before parsing it.
If that is how you want to proceed, then you'll want to adjust the way
you invoke Clang to check for and report syntax errors.  See the question
Is there a way to get a meaningfull error message when compiling code through libclang?
for details on how to do that.
Solution #2: Upgrade to a later version of Clang
For this example input, Clang 9 does not report the S1Grid field, but
Clang 11, 14, and 16 (all of the others I tested) do.  Evidently the
error recovery heuristics improved for this case.  Again, there's no
guarantee those versions will do the right thing on every input, but for
this one, they do.

Thank you for the response. After a bit more testing, I found that the include file is not processed because we are using CXTranslationUnit_SingleFileParse. We need this because we want to do code reflections on structs defined in a particular folder and not on any structs that are included by them. It doesn't look like clang can parse the source file with the knowledge of the includes without actually including the code in the header file in the translation unit.

I'm not sure what you mean by "code reflections", but if your goal is to ignore structs from included headers, or perhaps based on which folder the header is in, that can be done by examining the source location of each entity in the translation unit and ignoring those outside your intended scope.  (And that sort of filtering is required no matter what parser you use; there is no parser that will take header contents into account without incorporating them into the TU AST.)
